# How to convert tan radian to degree

Tags: math, trigonometry

I am trying to get tan degree of a number and since the language I'm using Swift only gives radian I have to convert the answer.

My problem is

tan(1) correctly gives me 1.5574 but using the formula I found online to convert to degrees

1.55574 * 180 / pi

doesn't give me 0.0175 that Im looking for.

Comment: You're applying the conversion to the result of `tan` (which isn't an angle), rather than the input, `1`, which has to be in radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Degrees to radians is (x * pi / 180).  However, you need to convert *before* passing the argument into `tan`.

```
math.tan(1 * math.pi / 180)
0.017455064928217585
```

Comment: Radians to degrees is x * 180/pi

Comment: Yea, I messed up the first version of the comment.  I fixed the post.

Comment: Is this difference for sin because I converted it after I got the result instead of before passing it.